# Informa RSS - Class missing error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, parsing, opml

I've set out some code for reading an OPML file for subscriptions from YouTube. The code comes from [Informa RSS here](http://informa.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)

When I run the code I get **class missing error**. The only reference to this I could find suggested the javaDOM version might be wrong since it was updated to DOM2.0 but failed to tell me how I could fix, it just said to use an older one and gave a link to a javaDOM version 0.7?

Now when I installed the JavaDOM 0.7 into the Library for Netbeans the error disappears until I try to run or compile it and it fails....

Now I dont know where to go with it.

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, my main problem is the OPML file has all the same tag information, ie

```
<opml version="1.1">
<body>
    <outline text="YouTube Subscriptions" title="YouTube Subscriptions">
            <outline text="PersonOne" title="PersonOne" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCuNfoe7ozooi0LZgp6JJS4A" />
            <outline text="PersonTwo" title="PersonTwo" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCVErFSr-jdTa_QE4PPSkVJw" />
            <outline text="Person Three" title="Person Three" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCittVr8imKanO_5KohzDbpg" />
        </outline>
    </body>
</opml>
```

..and there isn't enough information about how to handle this combination of tags in Java, Ive been searching for three days...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get [Informa 0.7.0-alpha2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/informa/) to read the subscriptions exported as an OPML file from YouTube. The OPML consists of one `outline` element that contains multiple `outline` child elements for each RSS subscription.

Informa's `OPMLParser` class only looked at `outline` elements inside the `body` element, which is how most OPML subscription lists are structured. It didn't look for child `outline` elements inside `outline`.

As an alternative solution, I used the Java XML parsing library [XOM](http://xom.nu/) 1.12.10. Here's the code to read the OPML file that YouTube produces:

```
try {
    // create an XML builder
    Builder bob = new Builder();
    // build an XML document from the OPML file
    Document doc = bob.build(new File("subscription_manager.xml"));
    // get the root element
    Element opml = doc.getRootElement();
    // get root's body element
    Element body = opml.getFirstChildElement("body");
    // get body's outline element
    Element outline = body.getFirstChildElement("outline");
    // get outline's child outline elements
    Elements outlines = outline.getChildElements("outline");
    // loop through those elements
    for (int i = 0; i < outlines.size(); i++) {
        // display each RSS feed's URL
        System.out.println(outlines.get(i).getAttributeValue("xmlUrl"));
    }            
} catch (ParsingException | IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

This code has these imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import nu.xom.Builder;
import nu.xom.Document;
import nu.xom.Element;
import nu.xom.Elements;
import nu.xom.ParsingException;
```